# ASP.Net 4.5 error on compiling

Tags: c#, asp.net

below is my code, when compiling am getting 3 errors as shown

Any help could be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.ModelBinding;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Build01
{
    public static class ModelBindingExtensions
    {

        public static ModelBindingExecutionContext GetModelBindingExecutionContext(this Page page)
        {
            return new ModelBindingExecutionContext
            {
                HttpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current),
                ModelState = page.ModelState
            };
        }
    }
}
```

> Error 1   'System.Web.ModelBinding.ModelBindingExecutionContext' does
>   not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments   Error  2   Property or
>   indexer 'HttpContext' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
>   Error 3   Property or indexer 'ModelState' cannot be assigned to -- it
>   is read only

Answer (score 1):

`ModelBindingExecutionContext` does not have a constructor that takes 0 arguments. [But it does have one that takes both a `HttpContext` and a `ModelStateDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551864(v=vs.110).aspx), so you need to pass those to the constructor:

```
return new ModelBindingExecutionContext(
    new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), page.ModelState);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the syntax incorrect for consuming a class constructor.  Rather than using `{ }` use `( )` as so:

```
    public static ModelBindingExecutionContext GetModelBindingExecutionContext(this Page page)
    {
        return new ModelBindingExecutionContext
        ( // note ( not {
            new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current),
            page.ModelState
        );
    }
```

The syntax of `{ }` can be used to set class properties, but only if they have public setters.  In this case `HttpContext` and `ModelState` need to be set through the objects constructor, and do not have public setters.